# Joining / Concat DNxHR HQ *without* re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

is it possible to precisely concatenate multiple DNxHR (HQ) videos into one without re-encoding?

It seems that [ffmpeg can only handle MPEG streams](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the streams have the same properties - resolution, pixel format, timebase, reference frame count, then they can be concatenated by ffmpeg. Strictly speaking, FFmpeg will concat non-matching streams, only throwing warnings for discontinuous timestamps in the input streams, but that output will not be accepted by most (or any) players.

Comment: Indeed, it worked flawlessly with this command: `ffmpeg -f concat -i mydnxhrfiles.txt -c copy result.mov`